# I am not able to switch to popup window, and From that window i want to select Item

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am trying to automate one webpage but i am facing issue what exactly I'm trying to do is first i am navigating to my destination webpage then entering information, then i have to choose category code for that i have to click on torch button up to this all working as per the code but then this part i am not able to automate this part ---> *a popup window or modal window open, which has its own link from that i am trying to select that code and popup window closes and code that i have selected is populated my input feed of main page*

so can any one help to automate this italic part
here is the my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import xlrd

url 
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\\Users\\lltt9166\\Desktop\\msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
main_page = driver.current_window_handle
username = driver.find_element_by_id("M__Id")
username.send_keys(myusername)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("M__Ida")
password.send_keys(mypassword)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='myForm']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/a/img")
button.click()

#finding GUT PO Local
gut_po = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"GUT PO Local Requestor"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.
gut_po.click()

#Non Catalog after clicking this i reached to mydestination webpage and filling input field from excel sheet
non_cata = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Non-Catalog Request"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.
non_cata.click()

#opening workbook
mlan = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\\Users\\lltt9166\\Desktop\\MSLA\\MSLA.xlsx")
sheet = mlan.sheet_by_index(3)
item = sheet.cell_value(1,1)

sheet2 = mlan.sheet_by_index(4)
cat = sheet2.cell_value(1,4)

#Entering Item Description item
desc = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"ItemDescription"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.
desc.send_keys(item)

#this torch icon and click this new window is opening upto this all part wrked
torc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/span[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span/a/img")
torc.click()

#Switching to popup window but here it showing you have not define popup 
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    if handle != main_page:
        popup = handle

driver.switch_to.window(popup)

quksele = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/span/div[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/img"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.
quksele.click()
```

and this is my error feed:

```
[12860:14596:0325/122239.202:ERROR:storage_reserve.cc(165)] Failed to open file to mark as storage reserve: C:\Users\lltt9166\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir2800_2073956399\Default\Code Cache\js

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55394/devtools/browser/30aae62f-9087-449a-b7a8-d6c94eaeb860
[12860:15216:0325/122239.520:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(376)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: 
kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string: 

[12860:15216:0325/122245.250:ERROR:profile_manager.cc(1794)] Cannot create profile at path C:\Users\lltt9166\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
[12860:15216:0325/122245.255:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [12:22:45.254] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[12860:15216:0325/122256.348:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "PSL: window.chrome.ntpSettingsPrivate.getPref does not have campaigns. [object Object] Thu Mar 25 2021 12:22:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", source: https://assets.msn.com/bundles/v1/edgeChromium/latest/vendors.2e0382f522ccf8ee14f0.js (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lltt9166\Desktop\Python\login.py", line 55, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.window(popup)
NameError: name 'popup' is not defined
PS C:\Users\lltt9166\Desktop\Python> [12860:15216:0325/122308.989:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Request has failed. [object Object] Thu Mar 25 2021 12:23:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", source: https://assets.msn.com/bundles/v1/edgeChromium/latest/vendors.2e0382f522ccf8ee14f0.js (1)
[12860:15216:0325/122308.989:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] " [object Object] Thu Mar 25 2021 12:23:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", source: https://assets.msn.com/bundles/v1/edgeChromium/latest/vendors.2e0382f522ccf8ee14f0.js (1)
```

this is i found that its not working
File "c:\Users\lltt9166\Desktop\Python\login.py", line 55, in 
driver.switch_to.window(popup)
NameError: name 'popup' is not defined
can any one help what are the possible way that i can resolve it out

[image]

Comment: driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) Should switch to the last window open.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan still it is not switching to that window do you know other possible way it showning time exception error i change time to 20 seconds still nothing changed

Comment: Are you sure it's another window?

Comment: shell i send screen shot ?@ArundeepChohan

Comment: It is kind of popup window when we go to stackoverflow then try to login with google account and jnew popup appears it has google account link like stuff @ArundeepChohan

Comment: Post the screenshot

Comment: @ArundeepChohan hi i have posted the screensshoot in background you can see the main page contains cart section and requisition and shop. and popup windows is conating code that i want to seletct using that quickselect item

Comment: If you right click and inspect it does those elements show up.

Comment: Yes It showing those element@ArundeepChohan

Comment: That's not a window.

Comment: so what it is?@ArundeepChohan I am new to this course so can you suggest that how can i perform or switch to that windwo

Answer (score 0):

Just change this part of code and your code will switch to the new window:

```
 main_page = driver.current_window_handle
 for handle in driver.window_handles:
   
   if handle != main_page:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)



quksele = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/span/div[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/img"))
    ) # Waits 10 second before element loads.
quksele.click()
```